# I can't use RegOpenKeyEx

Tags: c++, registry

I am having problems with reading the registry.
This function finds the number of entries in a registry path. It works perfectly, I have tested it:

```
void findNumberEntries(registryTest &INSTALLKEY) {

char buffer[50];
char size = sizeof(buffer);
int index = 0;

if(RegOpenKeyEx(INSTALLKEY.hKey,(LPTSTR)(INSTALLKEY.regpath.c_str()),0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,&INSTALLKEY.hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {     

    DWORD readEntry;

    do {
        readEntry = RegEnumValue(INSTALLKEY.hKey,index,(LPTSTR)buffer,(LPDWORD)&size,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        index++;
    }
    while(readEntry != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS);
}
INSTALLKEY.number = index;
RegCloseKey(INSTALLKEY.hKey);
}
```

now, the main function:

```
std::string regpath32 = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\";
struct registryTest {
HKEY hKey;
std::string regpath;
int number;
};

registryTest INSTALLKEY = {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regpath32};
findNumberEntries(INSTALLKEY);
printf("%d\n",INSTALLKEY.number);
system("PAUSE");
//until here everything works as it should

HKEY hKey = INSTALLKEY.hKey;
std::string regpath = INSTALLKEY.regpath;
char buffer[50];
char size = sizeof(buffer);
std::string bufferString;
DWORD regOpen = RegOpenKeyEx(INSTALLKEY.hKey,(LPTSTR)INSTALLKEY.regpath.c_str(),0,KEY_READ,&INSTALLKEY.hKey);
if(regOpen == ERROR_SUCCESS) //this is the part that fails.
{
    printf("Registry Key was successfully opened\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Unable to open registry key\n");
    LPVOID message; 
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, GetLastError(), NULL,(LPTSTR) &message, 0, NULL );
    MessageBox(NULL,(LPCTSTR)message,"ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

...rest of the code
```

I always get "Unable to open registry" and the error message I get is "There are no more files". What is the problem??

Comment: What version of windows? 32 or 64 bit? Is the process 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: It is 32 bit but on WinXP 32bit, I get "Registry Key was successfully opened". On Win7 64 bit I get this problem.

Comment: However, my findNumberEntries() function works even on Win7 64 bit... this is odd..

Comment: Store GetLastError value in some variable immediately after RegOpenKeyEx call, print its value together with FormatMessage result. Possibly "There are no more files" message is misleading.

Comment: Am I right in guessing that the call to `RegOpenKeyEx` in `findNumberEntries` is failing because UAC is on and you are requesting `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`.

Comment: On 64 bit windows you'll be redirected to the WOW64 node. You'd need to disable registry redirection or stop using the emulator and compile for 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that when you first open the registry key ,you assign it to hkey-member of your struct. So the second time this hkey doesn't contain the original basekey anymore.

change :

> DWORD regOpen =
>   RegOpenKeyEx(INSTALLKEY.hKey,(LPTSTR)INSTALLKEY.regpath.c_str(),0,KEY_READ,&INSTALLKEY.hKey);

into

> DWORD regOpen = RegOpenKeyEx(
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
>   ,(LPTSTR)INSTALLKEY.regpath.c_str(),0,KEY_READ,&INSTALLKEY.hKey);

or change this:

```
void findNumberEntries( registryTest &INSTALLKEY)   
{
  char buffer[50];
  char size = sizeof(buffer); 
  int index = 0; 
  HKEY hkOpen = 0; // can't use INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE for HKEY's;

  if (RegOpenKeyEx( INSTALLKEY.hKey ,(LPTSTR)(INSTALLKEY.regpath.c_str())
                   ,0,&hkOpen ) == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
  {
      // You should use RegQueryInfoKey for below code !
      DWORD readEntry;      
      do {
         readEntry = RegEnumValue( hkOpen ,index,(LPTSTR)buffer
                       ,(LPDWORD size,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
         index++;
     }
    while(readEntry != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS); }
    INSTALLKEY.number = index;
    RegCloseKey( hkOpen );
 }
```

Comment: Edwin this worked perfectly, thank you very much. However hKey is not always LOCAL_MACHINE and could be CURRENT_USER, I don't know in advance. This is why I try to keep track of it in my struct. What can I do? Also, I don't understand exactly what was the problem.

Comment: the problem is that you have overwritten the hkey member (which originally contained HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) with the value of the newly opened key. Instead you could use a local HKEY variable in findNumberEntries(...).

Comment: @jack: To get information on a HKEY you can call RegQueryInfoKey( ... ) which tells you all required info about that key.

Comment: INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE is a handle and my compiler does not let me assign it to an HKEY...what can I do?

Comment: @jack: my mistake ,just use 0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` in the second call as well, rather than just in the first. And on Win7 64-bit you may be running into the registry redirect craziness (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx).

EDIT: ah, you might just be getting an ERROR_CANTWRITE back (error code number 5). You might be able to ignore that and see if it still works.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that on Windows 7 64-bit that you are being redirected via [Registry Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can determine what keys are being redirected by calling [RegQueryReflectionKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you modify your code to output the actual integer value that is returned rather than a generic "Unable to open key", then it would be helpful. For example,

```
    long n = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("\\SOFTWARE"),
                      0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hk );
    if ( n == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
        cout << "OK" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed with value " << n << endl;
    }
```

Comment: I'm 100% certain that key is redirected, no need to look it up with RegQueryReflectionKey!

Comment: @David: Does not hurt to check :)